# RecyclerView - É possível mudar a view atual no evento de clique longo?

Tags: java, android

Em uma determinada parte do meu app irá ter um RecyclerView como uma lista de despesas como mostrado abaixo:

[image: Lista de despesas]

A questão é, quero que o usuário possa editar a qualquer momento as despesas apenas ao ter um longo click, assim substituindo por widgets editáveis, e ao final da edição, voltar para a view de apresentação padrão.

```
package br.com.ivesti.ivesmoney.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import br.com.ivesti.ivesmoney.R;
import br.com.ivesti.ivesmoney.database.ExpensesTable;

public class ExpensesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExpensesAdapter.ExpensesHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<ExpensesTable> mData = new ArrayList<>();

    public ExpensesAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull List<ExpensesTable> dataSet){
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mData = dataSet;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ExpensesHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        return new ExpensesHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.expenses_item, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ExpensesHolder holder, int position) {

        final ExpensesTable item = mData.get(position);
        final int type = item.type;



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    protected class ExpensesHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ImageView ivIcon;
        Spinner spType;
        EditText etValue;

        public ExpensesHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            ivIcon = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.expItemExpIcon);
            spType = (Spinner)itemView.findViewById(R.id.expItemSpinner);
            etValue = (EditText)itemView.findViewById(R.id.expItemValue);

        }
    }

}
```

Este é meu adapter, eu deixei a View de edição inflada como padrão, mas gostaria de poder muda-la no `onLongClick(View v)` e em seguida voltar para a View padrão

Answer (score 1):

Voce pode criar o onLongItenClick tanto dentro do adaptador como também no onCreate esse listener vai retornar a posição do objeto na lista e então tu pode passar essa posição para um método que será responsável por abrir um Dialog na tela.Esse dialog pode ter o layout totalmente customizado e após a edição da dispesa o usuario clica ok e volta para tela onde está a Recycler.Vou assumir que nao tenha problema chamar o onLongItemClick no onCreate:

1.no oncreate após criar a tua recycler:

```
TuarecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new 
 RecyclerItemClickListener(this,
TuarecyclerView, new 
 RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {



}

@Override
public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position) {
MetodoQueVaiCriarODialog( position);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

}
}));
```

Fora do onCreate tu cria o metodo     MetodoQueVaiCriarODialog( position);

2.Cria o layout daquilo que tu chamou de widget da forma que tu quer que ele seja apresentado ao usuariio quando este der o clique longo.O layout deve ser criado como qualquer outro lá em res>layout>new layout resourse file

3.abaixo o esqueleto do metodo que sera chamado quando tiver o clique longo:

```
private void MetodoQueVaiCriarODialog (final int position) {
final Dialog  dialogPersonalizado= new Dialog(NomeDaActivityOndeEstaARecycler.this);
dialogPersonalizado.setCancelable(false);//serve para evitar que o dialog feche 
//clicando fora dele isso obriga o usuário a clicar em algum botão de ação .se não for 
//necessário é so remover
dialogPersonalizado.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);//remove titulo 
//padrao
dialogPersonalizado.setContentView(R.layout.layout_que_tu_criou);
// nesse ponto tu tem que inicializar os componentes do layout_que_tu_criou vou deixar 
// o 
// exemplo de um textView e de um Button
TextView  nome=dialogPersonalizado.findViewById(R.id.Id_do_textView);
nome.setText(lista_de_despesas_usadas_na_recycler.get(position).getNome());
Button cancelar =dialogPersonalizado.findViewById(R.id.id_do_button_cancelar);
Button salvar=dialogPersonalizado.findViewById(R.id. id_do_button_salvar);
cancelar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dialogPersonalizado.dismiss;

    }
});
salvar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        /*execute aqui a ação necessária para salvar a alteração*/

    }
});

dialogPersonalizado.show();

}
```